# How to give relative path of image using fo:external-graphic to draw an image in pdf file generated?

Tags: java, xslt, pdf, xsl-fo

```
<fo:flow flow-name="xsl-region-body">
        <fo:block>
                    <fo:external-graphic width="85pt" height="35pt"  src="url(D:\WebSphere\AppServer\installedApps\ISLVPHP01G0\gcb_retail_appl2.ear\fcat27Web.war\images\eng\<image-name>.gif)"/>
                 </fo:block>
```

...
....

```
OutputStream        l_op_stream     =   null;
        byte    []          l_byte          =   null;
        InputStream         l_in_stream     =   null;

p_response.setHeader ("Cache-Control", "max-age=0"); //HttpServletResponse  p_response object 
        p_response.setHeader ("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        p_response.setHeader ("Pragma", "no-cache");
        p_response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0);
p_response.setHeader (
                "Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" 
                     +  p_attchFname + "\"" 
            );
```

....
....

```
FOProcessor l_processor =   new FOProcessor();
ByteArrayOutputStream   l_bos_temp      =   null;
                        l_processor.setOutputFormat (
                            FOProcessor.FORMAT_PDF
                        );
                        l_processor.setData (
                            new ByteArrayInputStream (
                                p_data.response.getBytes(xslEncoding)
                            )
                        );
                        l_processor.setTemplate (
                            l_in_stream
                        );

                        l_bos_temp  =   new ByteArrayOutputStream ();
                        l_processor.setOutput (l_bos_temp); //set output file           
                        l_processor.generate ();
```

I am using XSLT/XSL-FO for the UI part of my application. I have a `.xsl` file containing an absolute path of an image to display a bank logo as shown in the code inside `<fo:external-graphic>`. I want to replace the absolute path with a relative path to the image.

I have shown above the UI code and server side code in java.

I want to give relative path in 'src' tag in  tag instead of absolute path.

Please suggest me a way to do it.

Comment: Where do you store the image path in your stylesheet (the part you pseudo-reference with `<image-name>`)? I understand that you want to create a path dynamically, but you need to include more XSLT code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with your particular FO processor, but in general you can do this by implementing a custom `URIResolver`. For example using Apache FOP:

```
FOUserAgent fop = FopFactory.newInstance().newFOUserAgent();
fop.setURIResolver(new MyURIResolver());
```

Where `MyURIResolver` is something like:

```
public class MyURIResolver implements URIResolver {
    public Source resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException {
        InputStream is;
        //TODO get InputStream from file system, database, etc. based on href
        return new StreamSource(is);
    }
}
```

Whatever you pass to `url()` in the `src` attribute of `fo:external-graphic`, whether relative or absolute, will get passed to the `URIResolver` via the `href` parameter, allowing you to resolve it as you see fit.